# How to check a flow network contains unique maximum flow?

Tags: algorithm

My assignment asks to design an efficient algorithm to check whether a flow network contains unique maximum flow.  I have been searching anything I could but still having trouble understand the intuition behind this. How should I start a good approach ?

Comment: Hint: first, find a max-flow in your graph, there are several algorithms to do so. Then, you could modify your graph in some way (like changing weights on specific edges), and run the same algorithm to find a max-flow on your modified graph.

Comment: I got your idea and I'm pretty close to it. But I'm still stuck on how exactly a maximum flow is unique. Could you give an example such that a flow network contains a unique maximum flow? @m.raynal

Comment: A graph which is a single branch `(s -- u1 -- u2 -- .... -- un -- t)` would be an example of graph that has a single `s,t` flow. In general, a graph that has a single path from `s` to `t` is a graph that has a unique solution to the max `s,t`-flow problem.

Comment: @m.raynal Thanks, I have seen suggestion like run FF on the graph, then as we find the max flow, we decreased the capacities on each edges, then run FF one more time to see if we have two same max flow value.Which is similar to your idea, but this doesn't work for arbitrary flow network isn't ? In addition, this seems doesn't work for me either, if we have a flow network with only one edge goes to t has capacity of 1, if we run FF and decreased each edge, we end up that one edge goes to t became 0 capacity. And we found no more other max flow, but this  is obviously not true.

Comment: Some other suggestions are detect cycles in residual graph, I'm still having trouble of understand this idea.

Comment: You're right, decreasing every edge of the max-flow and running again FF will not work in the general case. But if you decrease the capacity on each edge of the max-flow *one by one* and run a FF each time, then, you will get the answer you're looking for :-) I'm sorry I didn't give you a straight answer, but since it's an assignment I think it's much better if you figure out things by yourself :-)

Comment: @m.raynal Thanks, that makes much more sense now, but I’m still thinking about arbitrary flow network. FF doesn’t work for non-integer capcacities isn't? Any addition hints for this case?

Comment: I think it should, because since we have a finite number of weights, there must be a way to approximate the weights to a rational value without messing up with the comparison of their sums. Then from rational to integer, all we have to do is multiply by a big enough value all the weights .... but I may be wrong, I never thought about real value weights.

Comment: Can we use Edmonds Karp instead FF then? Not sure if it still works but it handles irrational capacities. @m.raynal